# EF Core: How to query a SQL View

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-view, ef-core-2.1

I have a SQL View in my DB called 'dbo.Viewtest'. This view combines the data of 2 other tables, that have identical column types. The view also adds a column to show from which table the data originated.

This is what the SQL View looks like in SQL Server Object Explorer:

#### dbo.ViewTest

Id | Type | Content | Location

1  | h1   | Welcome!| Home

2  | p    | Log in  | Home

3  | h2   | guide   | Home

1  | h1   | info    | Events

2  | p    | follow  | Events

This view is created from 2 tables, one of which is called 'HomeContent' and the other 'EventsContent' (hence the location column). The view was created, using the following code:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE VIEW ViewTest AS " +
                "SELECT Id, Type, Content, 'Home' location FROM HomeContent UNION ALL " +
                "SELECT Id, Type, Content, 'Evenementen' FROM EvenementenContent");

        }
```

I then added a Model Class as follows:

```
  [Table("ViewTest")]
    public class TestViewContent
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally, i've added it to my DbContext:

```
 public DbSet<TestViewContent> TestViewContent { get; set; }
```

Now, here is where things start breaking. When i try to display this SQL View, using EF Core, i get the following broken output:

Id | Type | Content | Location

1  | h1   | Welcome!| Home

2  | p    | Log in  | Home

3  | h2   | guide   | Home

1  | h1   | Welcome | Home

2  | p    | log in  | Home

As you can see, for whatever reason when i try to display the SQL View, the data 'loops-around' when data from the 'Events' table is supposed to show. So for whatever reason, it only displays data from the home table.

The code that i use for displaying the SQL View is:

```
 private readonly DbApplicationContext_context;

        public TestViewContentController(DbApplicationContext_context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.TestViewContent.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Is there anyone who could help me out here? In case it isn't possible to display SQL-Views, does anyone know of a better way to combine multiple tables and add a 'Location' column to trace the table from where the data originated? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: off-topic comment: *2 other tables, that have identical column types* ... add Location column and merge those tables into one

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! The problem with just combining the 2 tables into one, is that the 2 different tables get data added to them separately, quite often. The tables are linked to an editing platform for a website and i'm afraid that it's impossible to constantly update a combined table, when data gets added to one table

Comment: google for Keyless Entity Types

Comment: Try to remove `[Key]` attribute from your model. In any case, your `Id` value in the view is not unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you put `[Key]` on the `Id` property, but your `VIEW` produces duplicate values in the `Id` column when combining the two tables. EF Core then probably goes "Ah there is `Id`=1 again, I have that row already, so I will reuse it".

There are three possible fixes:

**(1)** Define a separate column for the VIEW that is guaranteed to generate **unique values**, and then use that column in EF Core as the `[Key]`.

or

**(2)** Keep the VIEW as it is, then in EF Core define a **composite primary key**. Note that EF Core does not support creating a composite key using the `[Key]` attribute, you need to [use the Fluent API **`HasKey()`** function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations), in this case for the `Location` and `Id` properties.

or

**(3)** Leave out the `[Key]` altogether, you may not actually need it, as described in the docs here: [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types).

Comment: Thank you! It took me some time, but you were absolutely right Peter. It was indeed the lack of a primary key. Issue is fixed now!